# What is the purpose of the "tree-***" family of GCC optimization options?

Tags: c, optimization, gcc

Reading gcc's manual, I see a family of `-ftree-***` optimization options. What is the purpose of these options? What are these "trees"?

Comment: I imagine that refers to the abstract syntax tree which represents your program.

Answer (score 6):

They are optimizer passes that work on the (SSA) trees inside the compiler, rather than on the RTL (register transfer language) level.

For an overview what this is about, see the GCC internals documentation: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/

For an introduction about SSA, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_single_assignment_form

Comment: Thanks. I have a feeling that I am opening a can of worms here (I am not a compilers guy), but can you elaborate a little bit on these SSA trees? What is the difference between "inside the compiler" and "on the RTL level"?

Comment: @ysap: see http://www.redhat.com/magazine/002dec04/features/gcc/figs/tree-ssa-phases.png from http://www.redhat.com/magazine/002dec04/features/gcc/ for an overview of gcc compilation steps

Comment: @ysap: This is a large topic. In addition to the nice links posted by Christoph, see the links I added in my edit.

Comment: Just to be clear, it's 'tree' vs. 'RTL', not 'inside' vs. 'RTL'. Both tree-SSA and RTL optimizers are most decidedly inside the compiler.